# Uploading big file (video size > 10 MB) using grails

Tags: grails, video, file-upload, video-streaming

Working with Grails 3.* Framework.
Iam trying to upload a video file, the size will be grater than 10 MB.

Below is the code, which works perfectly for storing image files in server, which is uploaded from client browser

```
File fileIns = new File("/opt/a.jpg")
fileIns << params.image
```

Can I use the same code for saving videos.
if so, params.video may consume a huge memory, how can I optimize it.

Or any other methods to stream part by part and save it as video?

How whatsapp and telegram are used for transferring video files into the server?

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If You are dealing with large data, I'd suggest going full java. 
Check [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html) link about using **Streaming**. 
Another chance is using **HTTPClient**. [Read this](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365153/HttpClient-and-FileUpload)